# identify substring using str.contains by mixing AND and OR

Tags: python, regex, string, substring, contains

I am trying to identify substrings in a given string using str.contains while mixing the OR and AND

I know that OR can be represented by |

```
str.contains("error|break|insufficient")
```

and that AND can be represented by AND

```
str.contains("error|break|insufficient") & str.contains("status")
```

I would like to mix the OR and AND together. Example is to identify strings that have "error" OR "break OR ("insufficient" AND "status")

So for sentence like
"error break insufficient" -> it will be able to identify. But now is not able to because there is no "status" in the sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
import pandas as pd

# toy data
s = pd.Series(["hello", "world", "simple", "error", "break", "insufficient something status", "status"])

# create and mask
insufficient_and_status = s.str.contains("insufficient") & s.str.contains("status")

# create or mask
break_or_error = s.str.contains("error|break", regex=True)

# or the two mask
mask = break_or_error | insufficient_and_status

res = s[mask]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
3                            error
4                            break
5    insufficient something status
dtype: object
```

Alternative, using a single regex:

```
mask = s.str.contains("error|break|(insufficient.+status|status.+insufficient)", regex=True)

res = s[mask]
print(res)
```

The alternative is based on the fact that if the string contains insufficient and status then at least one of the patterns `insufficient.+status` or `status.+insufficient` matches (i.e. or insufficient occurs first or status does)

Comment: works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: @inic72 Glad I could help!

Comment: Mesjo is there a way to include AND NOT in as well in the single regex method
str.contains("error|break|(insufficient.+status|status.+insufficient)?

Comment: @inic72 I'm not sure